# GAEL failing to deploy all folders of website

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have been using GAEL for about five years now and have not come across this problem before in that time.

Every time I try to deploy a new version of my website to Google I now get an error that module lib could not be found.(Error in Google Logs). When I load the page I see this:

**"Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request."**

I have checked that the module is there but for some reason it isnt uploading it to Google. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

It also seems that if I deploy it from another work email that it deploys the lib module but doesnt deploy the CSS folder so the styling of the website is not correct. These two problems must be linked in some way I would imagine. It just seems very strange.

Comment: You'll need to clarify what "GAEL" is (as opposed to just GAE).

Comment: GoogleAppEngineLauncher I presume

Comment: Yes GoogleAppEngineLauncher

Comment: Can you try using appcfg from the command line? Can you post the structure of your project? What do you mean "if i try from another work email"?